# CONSUME ABAP stack OData from JAVA Stack

Tags: java, abap, sap-solution-manager

I have a ABAP application up and running in ABAP Stack of my Solman.
If I build a UI5 application and deploy it in JAVA Stack, will I able to consume the ABAP OData from the UI5 application. If yes, how we can do this since both are in different stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Generally yes**, your SAPUI5 application will be able to consume the OData service.

The "generally" means that you may encounter issues with the *same origin policy* that browsers apply as a safety regulation, but there are usually ways to solve that.

In theory, SAPUI5 applications can connect to any OData service, no matter what system or stack that service resides in - for the application, it is only a URL. You can even connect to OData services hosted by systems other than SAP, as OData is an open standard.

The OData service must be visible in the application's network zone, of course.

Comment: Thanks Florian, but is it possible open a safe cross origin connection in ABAP stack?

Comment: I know that using SAP Gateway enables you to "republish" OData services that reside in one ABAP system on another ABAP system, thus redeclaring the origin. This is commonly used to serve all SAPUI5 applications from a single frontend hub, while the actual data calls are delegated to the real backend data-providing systems. When mixing Java and ABAP stacks, I don't know whether there is a similar solution.